# SXA Unrecognized Guid format on certain URL path

Tags: sxa

Our site has language embedding enabled, so our site URL is `https://{siteUrl}/en`
But when I mistakenly omitted `en` and typed a path (which is a two-letter word, e.g. `https://{siteUrl}/gg` it throws the Unrecognized Guid format exception.

This applies to every 2-letter suffix, even if it doesn't have a correlating page.

Is this a known issue, is there a patch available for this?

We use Sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.9

Comment: Does this link help? - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/617781

Comment: If so, this is an issue in Sitecore 8.2 Update-5 - 9.2 Initial Release, you may have to upgrade to Sitecore 9.3 to fix it I guess.. Or you can also try contacting Sitecore support

Comment: I did find this KB but our AlwaysAppendRevision is set to false, so I don't think it satisfies the patch's scenario.

Comment: Have you checked it through ShowConfig.aspx @Lala ? https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/view-configuration-changes.html